# How to change annotated text font color to red?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have this existing Excel-based check list (that's black font color); where I need to add text comments in red font color.  What's the easiest way possible to keep everything I type on the Excel document in red color?

Comment: This appears to be a `superuser` question. Having said that, you want the default comment text color to be red and keep the checklist as black?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to re-paint all **Comments** in red once they have been entered:

```
Sub BetterRedThan()
    Dim cmt As Comment
    If ActiveSheet.Comments.Count = 0 Then
        Range("A1").AddComment
    End If
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        cmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    Next cmt
End Sub
```